# Send Bulk SMS via Twilio Rest API with PHP

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am using [Twilio PHP Library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/), and i want to send SMS messages to a big list of people using Twilio PHP REST API. I have a text file, that contains the list of unique phone numbers (approx 1000 members).

Currently my plan was to create a cron job, which parses the text file, and makes a REST API call for each of the phone numbers in the file.

Ex:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$sms_sent = $client->messages->create(
    '+1xxxxxxxxxx',
    array(
        'from' => '+1xxxxxxxxxx',
        'body' => "XXXXXX XXXXXX",
        'statusCallback' => "http://myapplication_callback_url"
    )
);
```

But i wanted to know, whether Twilio can do the job for me (like i will upload the text file to Twilio, and Twilio will process the file and send SMS to each number in it).

Is there any option like this with Twilio? I have read about the BULK SMS option [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-send-bulk-sms-messages-in-php), but that seems like it sends out a static message to all the users. I need to send unique message to each user. How is this possible with Twilio? Please let me know.

**EDIT: 27-09-2017:**
I have heard about [Twilio COPILOT](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages-copilot), but not sure how to use that service.

Comment: Why not ask https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new ? It's not quite a programming question.

Comment: Where is that `unique message to each user` coming from if what you say is you want to upload a text file with numbers to Twilio?

Comment: @AlexBaban I can also specify a web service url which outputs a unique message for each call, which Twilio can probably use to send message to users, while parsing the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Just to distill your problem, you need to send about 1000 unique messages to users, right?

If that's the case, then this is what you need to do.

Since the message is unique to each number, you need to [make an API call to the Twilio REST API to send each message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages) individually. Twilio caps the message sending at 1 message per number per second. If you are already over this limit, then Twilio will queue those messages up for you. It should not take 5 seconds per API call.

This is the case if you use one number, like in your original example. For 1000 messages it will take almost 17 minutes to send them all.

However, you can use a messaging service to speed this up. A messaging service is a pool of numbers and other services provided by Copilot (including geo matching numbers, alphanumeric sender fallback and other such things). For sending a lot of messages, like in this case, the number pool is the important part because each Twilio number you are sending from can send 1 message per second. So if you add 2 numbers to the messaging service you can send 2 messages per second, if you add 10 numbers to the pool you can send 10 a second.

To send messages using a messaging service and number pool, like this, you need to [create a messaging service in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/services). Add or buy numbers for the pool. Then, get the messaging service SID:

[image: Find the messaging service SID in your Twilio console where you created the service.]

You can then use the messaging service SID in place of the from number in your call to the API.

```
$sms_sent = $client->messages->create(
    '+1xxxxxxxxxx',
    array(
        'from' => 'MESSAGING SERVICE SID',
        'body' => "XXXXXX XXXXXX",
        'statusCallback' => "http://myapplication_callback_url"
    )
);
```

Then your messages will be fanned out by the messaging service.

Notably, if you need to send 1000 messages in a day, we recommend you spread that out over at least 4 numbers as US carriers start to block long code numbers that are used more than that. Check out more in our [guidelines for sending SMS messages to the US](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/us).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: This definitely helps a lot. Thanks for your answer. I have one question regarding sending of messages. In your code, where should i specify the multiple numbers? There is only one number as far as i can see ('+1xxxxxxxxxx'). Can i make this an array of 1000 numbers?

Comment: Oh, sorry. You would need to iterate over your 1000 numbers and call `$client->messages->create` for each of them.

Comment: I would give it a try and let you know how it went... thanks for the prompt reply :)

Comment: No worries, let me know how it goes!

Comment: I want to know, whether the From phone number i use while sending an individual message, can be used as the Phone Number in a Messaging Service. As per the documentation at: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages-copilot#add-phone-numbers-to-a-service, i am not sure whether the phone number i have purchased is the one i can use.

Comment: Yep, you can add the phone number you have already purchased to the messaging service. Just edit your service and on the left you will see a menu item "Numbers". Click that, then on the next page click the + button. That gives you the option to add existing numbers or buy new ones.

Comment: Finally i am able to configure the Phone number for my messaging service, under Twilio Dashboard, and send bulk SMS using a Cron job (looping the array of 1000 numbers). Thank you :)

Comment: Hooray! Glad to hear it. If this has helped you, please do mark the answer as correct so that others can see it helped too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. First configure your number properly for notification and then use my code:

```
$message = 'Any text message';
$to = array();
foreach ($users as $user) { 
    $to[] = '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"'.$user->phone_number.'"}';
}

$sid    = 'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID';
$token  = 'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN';
$services_id = 'TWILIO_SERVICE_ID';
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);


$notification = $twilio
->notify->services($services_id)
->notifications->create([
    "toBinding" => $to,
    "body" => $message
]);
```

Comment: How would you go about avoiding a 504 timeout with this code? I have 2,000 numbers and I keep getting a timeout error.

Answer (score -1):

do you have the ability to create an SQL connection? 1 column to house the number to call, one column for the message content?

you can then loop through the rows in the table with your script above to fire off your messages one at a time.

```
//spaghetti code, will not work
//1. Create MySQL Connection
//2. loop through table
foreach($row as $number=>$message) {
$sms_sent = $client->messages->create(
    $number,
    array(
        'from' => '+1xxxxxxxxxx',
        'body' => $message,
        'statusCallback' => "http://myapplication_callback_url"
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: This idea seems to be good as a cron job, but to loop through 1000 records, and send messages one by one takes more than an hour (assuming 5 seconds per API call). I am expecting a simpler solution from Twilio.